# How to pass vue data to laravel @include

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I want to pass the Vue data to Laravel include
Let say for example:

```
 @include('sample-form', then pass vue data here)
```

as usual it looks similar to this:

```
 @include('sample-form', ['id' => $data]);
```

But when includes Vue data like the first statement above it will returns error on my blade.

Here's my code:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" :data-target="'#edit_' + attribute.id" class="btn btn-info btn-xs radius"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</button>
```

And here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
@include('modals.edit-modal', :data-target="'#edit_' + attribute.id")
```

How should we do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Put before your Vue app script in blade template:

```html
<script>
Vue.prototype._data = {!! json_encode(['id' => $id] !!};
</script>
```

Now, you can access data from Vue like:

```js
methods: {
    test() {
        alert(this._data.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thanks for your feedback. Please review my updated post. I have added some code snippets on it.

Comment: @totski, how you defined Vue app?

Comment: I defined it on a public js folder in laravel in just included on blade like this:
<script src="{{ asset('js/create-item.js') }}"></script>